# Date value returns random integer - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
select 31/10/2016 as date from dual;
```

Retuns me a long integer value.

Whereas,

```
select '31/10/2016' as date from dual;
```

Gives me the required result.

What is the transformation happening when we give the date value without quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non of them are right.

The 1st is an arithmetic computation.

```
31/10/2016 = ((31 / 10) / 2016) = 3.1 / 2016 = 0.00153...
```

The 2nd is a string

```
select '31/10/2016' + 1 from dual;
```

> ORA-01722: invalid number

---

ANSI/ISO Dates literals are written as

```
DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

[Datetime Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062)

In your case

```
DATE '2016-10-31'
```

---

```
select DATE '2016-10-31' + 1 from dual;
```

> 2016-11-01 00:00:00

---

P.s.
`date` is a reserved word.
You couldn't have used it as an alias for your columns without getting a parsing error.

[B Oracle Reserved Words, Keywords, and Namespaces](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e10830/appb.htm)

Comment: Is it necessay to specify the datatype of the column, prefix to the hardcoded values?

Comment: It is not a datatype but part of the syntax. It is not as you could replace it with another type e.g. varchar or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

`select 31/10/2016` : Its arithmetic operations ( dividation )

`select '31/10/2016'` :  Using quotes its become string. Single quotes delimit a string constant or a date/time constant.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute

> select 31/10/2016 as date from dual;

Oracle interprets it as a airthmatic division operation and divides 31 by 10 and result by again 2016 .

When you execute

> select '31/10/2016' as date from dual;

Oracle interprets as it as a string and it will throw error since Date is a reserved keyword and you cannot use reserve keywords either as column names or as alias.

The right way to do it as below:

> select to_date('31/10/2016','dd/mm/yyyy') as dte from dual;